# notifyDataSetChanged(); is not working in ExpandableRecyclerAdapter in android

Tags: android

I am using this link to implement expandableRecyclerView in my project.

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/expand-a-recyclerview-in-four-steps/

This is my code so far.

```
public class ActivityProductList extends AppCompatActivity {

  private android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView = null;
  private RecyclerView recyclerView;
  MyAdapter adapter;
  List<ParentListItem> parentListItems = new ArrayList<>();
  List<ParentListItem> originalProductList = new ArrayList<>();
  String keyword = null;
  int categoryId = 0;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

      Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
      getSupportActionBar().setTitle("PRODUCTS");
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

      recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.crime_recycler_view);
      recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
      adapter = new MyAdapter(this, originalProductList);
      //adapter.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
      getProducts();
  }

  private void getProducts() {
      originalProductList.clear();
      originalProductList.addAll(Utility.getParentListItems());
      Utility.displayToast("in fetch: " + originalProductList.size());
      adapter.addData(originalProductList);
  }


  public class MyAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter<MyAdapter.ProductParentViewHolder, MyAdapter.ProductChildViewHolder> {

      private LayoutInflater mInflater;
      private Context context;
      private List<? extends ParentListItem> mParentItemList;

      public MyAdapter(Context context, List<ParentListItem> itemList) {
          super(itemList);
          mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
          this.context = context;
          this.mParentItemList = itemList;
      }

      public void addData(List<ParentListItem> itemList) {
          this.mParentItemList = itemList;
          notifyDataSetChanged();
      }

     @Override
      public ProductParentViewHolder onCreateParentViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
          View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime_parent, viewGroup, false);
          return new ProductParentViewHolder(view);
      }

      @Override
      public ProductChildViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
          View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime_child, viewGroup, false);
          return new ProductChildViewHolder(view);
      }

      @Override
      public void onBindParentViewHolder(ProductParentViewHolder crimeParentViewHolder, int i, ParentListItem parentListItem) {
          Product product = (Product) parentListItem;
          crimeParentViewHolder.productName.setText(product.getBrandName() + " " + product.getProductName());
          Glide.with(context)
                  .load(product.getProductImagePath())
                  .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                  .error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                  .into(crimeParentViewHolder.thumbnail);
      }

      @Override
      public void onBindChildViewHolder(ProductChildViewHolder productChildViewHolder, int i, Object childListItem) {
          final ProductVariant productVariant = (ProductVariant) childListItem;
          productChildViewHolder.mCrimeDateText.setText(productVariant.getVariantName());
          productChildViewHolder.variantMrp.setText(productVariant.getMRP().toString());
          productChildViewHolder.variantSellPrice.setText(productVariant.getSellPrice().toString());
      }

      public class ProductParentViewHolder extends ParentViewHolder {
          private static final float INITIAL_POSITION = 0.0f;
          private static final float ROTATED_POSITION = 180f;
          private final boolean HONEYCOMB_AND_ABOVE = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;

          public TextView productName;
          public ImageView thumbnail;
          public ImageButton mParentDropDownArrow;

          public ProductParentViewHolder(View itemView) {
              super(itemView);

              productName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productName);
              thumbnail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
              // mParentDropDownArrow = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_list_item_expand_arrow);
          }

          @SuppressLint("NewApi")
          @Override
          public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
              super.setExpanded(expanded);
              if (!HONEYCOMB_AND_ABOVE) {
                  return;
              }

              if (expanded) {
                  // mParentDropDownArrow.setRotation(ROTATED_POSITION);
              } else {
                  // mParentDropDownArrow.setRotation(INITIAL_POSITION);
              }
          }
      }

      public class ProductChildViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {

          public TextView mCrimeDateText;
          public TextView variantMrp;
          public TextView variantSellPrice;
          public Button btnProductDetailAddToCart, btnProductDetailPlus, btnProductDetailMinus, btnProductDetailQty;


          public ProductChildViewHolder(View itemView) {
              super(itemView);

              mCrimeDateText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.variantName);
              variantMrp = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productVariantMrp);
              variantSellPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.productVariantSellPrice);
              btnProductDetailAddToCart = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnProductDetailAddToCart);
              btnProductDetailPlus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnProductDetailPlus);
              btnProductDetailMinus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnProductDetailMinus);
              btnProductDetailQty = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnProductDetailQty);

          }
      }
  }
}
```

The problem is with getProducts(). I am getting the data here correctly and passing it to adapter and calling notifyDataSetChanged(); in adapter. But UI is not getting updated.

Can anyone help me on this what's missing?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() generates a datasetchange event but you need a callback/listener to handle the event. "onDatasetChange" method perhaps? Did you click on the github link?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of your code, you are calling adapter notify inside adapter, this might be not able to refresh listview.

So use below code, it will work. Comment addData() method.

```
   private void getProducts() {
         originalProductList.clear();
         originalProductList.addAll(Utility.getParentListItems());
         Utility.displayToast("in fetch: " + originalProductList.size());
         //adapter.addData(originalProductList);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `addData()` method inside your `adapter`, change this line of code,

```
 this.mParentItemList = itemList;
```

to

```
this.mParentItemList.addAll(itemList);
```

and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`,

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But these types are different. private List<? extends ParentListItem> mParentItemList; and List<ParentListItem> itemList, how to fix, any idea?

Comment: no, I am using work around. assigning a new adapter to adapter and then setadapter. adapter = new MyAdapter(this, originalProductList);
      //adapter.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: In your first comment , the former is a generic so just type casting will remove the compile error like adding ((ParentListItem) itemList) in your addData() method

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public class MyAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter<MyAdapter.ProductParentViewHolder, MyAdapter.ProductChildViewHolder> {

  private LayoutInflater mInflater;
  private Context context;
  private List<ParentListItem> mParentItemList;

  public MyAdapter(Context context, List<ParentListItem> itemList) {
      super(itemList);
      mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
      this.context = context;
      this.mParentItemList = itemList;
  }

  public void addData(List<ParentListItem> itemList) {
      this.mParentItemList = itemList;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Comment: I tried, it is not working. In my code i am no where using mParentItemList. What i understood i need to call super(itemList); in addData() but constructor i can't call. and they have no function exposed to set itemList in super class.

Comment: What i have done is your "private List<? extends ParentListItem> " is not same as List<ParentListItem> and in your code in addData method still you are assigning  List<> values to List<? extends> , that's why  I have assigned List<ParentListItem> values to the same kind of object